# How do I Set Up the vue-burger-menu in My Vue project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I have spent some time trying to figure how to go about Setting up the vue-burger-menu in my vu3 project, but I cant still seem to get it. After installation, the setup process is a bit confusing. Please can anyone help with an idea of how I can go about it? [**I followed this guide**](https://vuejsexamples.com/an-off-canvas-sidebar-vue-component/). I'll really appreciate thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Very Easy.

Pay attention to the Vue version:

- [vue-burger-menu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-burger-menu) for Vue v2
- [vue3-burger-menu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-burger-menu) for Vue v3

Check the following Code Sandbox for the Vue 3 version

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-p3cfkq

[image]